# How do make a regular expression to match file paths?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I've been playing with this command for about an hour or two and I'm afraid I may have lost objectivity. **The goal is to match only relative file paths given to bash.**

The first relative path `.` or `./some/file/path`

The second relative path is `..` or `../some/file/path`

Where the length of "/some/file/path" is arbitrary.

I've been using `grep` within `bash` to try and figure out how to implement it in to my script so that I can expand it to it's absolute file path so that `./some/file/path` or `../some/file/path` becomes `/the/absolute/file/path`; which I've already figure out.

**My problem is matching the relative path.**

The code I've been using is

```
echo "../some/file/path" | egrep '\.{1}/?[[:graph:]]?+$'
```

and

```
echo "../some/file/path" | egrep '\.{2}/?[[:graph:]]?+$'
```

and I've narrowed my issue down to being

```
echo ".." | egrep '\.{2}'
```

will match the dot as long as it has `2 + n` occurrences, **not exactly 2 occurrences** as expected. The same thing happens when I change it to

```
echo ".." | egrep '\.{1}'
```

will still match for some reason I can't figure out.

The final implementation is supposed to work something like this

```
 41 _expand_relative_path () {
 42         if [[ "$1" =~ ^\.{1}/?[[:graph:]]?+$ ]]; then
 43                 echo "."
 44         elif [[ "$1" =~ ^\.{2}/?[[:graph:]]?+$ ]]; then
 45                 echo ".."
 46         else    
 47                 echo "$1"
 48         fi
 49 }
```

According to my text book, the specifier {n} will match the preceding element if it occurs exactly n times. But it doesn't do that! It matches if it is n or more times! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A path that does not start with `/` is relative..

Comment: you're saying that '^[^/]\.?\.?/?[[:graph:]]+$' is the simpler expression. is there a way to identify the . element exactly n times with the rest of my expression?

Comment: Why do you need this? And no, a rwkative path is just a `[^/].*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex that matches a relative path is one that doesn't start with a slash:

```
^[^/].*
```

Comment: Not working for me. Please see the link. It is only the machine in the first line, not the relative paths.
I have post the screenshot at https://i.imgur.com/XXI6Osq.png.

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed This regex matches all *relative* paths. What is the path you want to match. Type it; don't post a link to an image of it.

Answer (score 1):

the issue with `^\.{1}/?[[:graph:]]?+$` is that the `/` has been designated as optional, and the following `[[:graph:]]` character class matches anything *visible*, including more periods.  also, you've quantified your character class with `?+`, which means "zero or once, possessive": it ain't gotta match, but if it does, will not "give up" what it matched to let the rest of the pattern try to succeed - probably not what you wanted there.

when you say `echo ".." | egrep '\.{2}'`, what you're saying is "string contains, at some point, two periods in a row" - but that doesn't mean it can't have more periods or anything else, not without `^` and `$` anchors anyway, which would limit to *exactly and only* two periods.

as others note, any path not starting with `/` is relative so `^[^/].*` works. But if you wanted to find relative paths that are in a text file with some other text, this may be useful:

```
(\.{1,2}(?:\/[[:alnum:]]*)*)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hA0fV6/2) output:

[image]

Comment: I noticed you used a pcre, I haven't seen the : before. What does that do? For example `(?:\/[[` within the second subexpression.

Comment: Those are grouping only parens `(?:pattern)`, they do not capture. You might need pcregrep instead of egrep to use those...

Comment: I thought the parentheses `(` `)` were for grouping? **I meant the colon `:` specifically within the subexpression**, right after the `?` quantifier for matching an element zero or one time.

Comment: `(Pattern)` would capture Pattern in the match result *and* work for grouping, but `(?:Pattern)` only groups and does not capture anything

Comment: And actually the outer parentheses aren't necessary here

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> echo ".." | egrep '\.{2}'
> ```
>
> will match the dot as long as it has 2 + n occurrences, not exactly 2
>   occurrences as expected.

Well yes.  By default, `grep` print lines that *contain* the pattern.  Any line that contains more than two consecutive dots necessarily contains two consecutive dots, so the pattern matches.

> The same thing happens when I change it to
>
> ```
> echo ".." | egrep '\.{1}'
> ```
>
> will still match for some reason I can't figure out.

Same thing: the string ".." contains a '.', therefore it matches the pattern.

Consider, now, your original pattern, `'\.{2}/?[[:graph:]]?+$'`:

1. In the first place, observe that it is not anchored to the beginning of the string, so it will match absolute paths of the form `/foo/bar../baz` (and others).  You need an initial `^` in the pattern to anchor it.
2. You make the presence of a `/` after the leading dots optional by using the `?` quantifier.  It is unclear why you do this if your objective is specifically to match paths where the first segment is `..`.  The only thing I can think of is that you want to match the path that is exactly `..` itself, which your pattern does, but it is *too* accepting.
3. The next segment is `[[:graph:]]?+`, which seems an odd way to write the more standard `[[:graph:]]*`.  Additionally, you seem here to be relying on the fact that `[[:graph:]]` will match the `/` character, which it will, so you might as well roll the preceding optional `/` right into the character class: `'^\.{2}[[:graph:]]*$'`.
4. Now observe that `[[:graph:]]` *also* matches `.`.  This now explains why the original pattern matches strings that contain more than two consecutive dots: the first two are matched by the `\.{2}`, nothing is matched by `/?`, and the remaining dots (and perhaps other characters) are matched by `[[:graph:]]?+`.
5. Finally, consider that `\.\.` is shorter and clearer than `\.{2}`, and especially that plain `\.` is *far* clearer than `\.{1}`.

Of course, in his answer, @Bohemian presents the natural pattern for matching every possible relative path, but if you wanted a pattern to specifically match paths whose first segments are `.` or `..`, including those without other segments, and without a trailing `/` then you might try this:

```
egrep '^\.{1,2}(/.*[^/])?$'
```

- It is anchored at the beginning (`^`) and at the end (`$`), so it performs whole-line matches (only).
- matching lines must begin with one or two dots (`\.{1,2}`)
- Anything else is optional (`(...)?`), but if that optional segment is present then it must begin with a `/` and end with a character that is not `/`.  In between can be any number, including zero, of any character (`.*`).
- Note that Unix file and directory names can contain whitespace and non-graphical characters, so using `[:graph:]` in your original pattern restricted it to a subset of possible paths.

Comment: I really like how you broke down my expression and explained what was happening at each step. You are correct in your assumptions. Although, it is my fault, I left out the fact that `./` and `../` were both allowed as well which explains why I made that optional.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows: `^.*\\(?!.*\\)(.*)$`

or for Linux: `^.*/(?!.*/)(.*)$`

or for both:

`^.*(?:\\|/)(?!.*(?:\\|/))(.*)$`

It matches the `filename.extension` in a `.../path/filename.extension` or `...\path\filename.extension` as it checks for the last occurrence of either `\` or `/` and then captures every character from that point forward.